# How to parse this multi dimensional JSON with PHP to fetch correct array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing, formatting

I have JSON which is formatted like example below which is correct way to loop whole file to catch "IWANTTHIS" values? All arrays are on same level in JSON ("some:products"). Just too complicated JSON for me in this afternoon...

```
{
  "type": "page",
  "pageType": "section",
  "_links": {},
  "_embedded": {
  "somkindof:blocks": [
    {
     "somevalue": 25,
     "_embedded": {
     "some:products": [
     {
      "system": {
      "availability": {},
      "IWANTTHIS": "20284",
      "hhhh": []
      },
....
```

I tried something like this but I cant catch values formatted like in my example.

```
$jfo = json_decode($vcurl);
$channel = $jfo->_embedded->[somkindof:blocks];

var_dump $channel;
```

Comment: Try `$channel = $jfo->_embedded->{'somkindof:blocks'}` (You may find using it as an array easier, look at json_decode parameter 2 in the PHP docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things get easier if you decode the JSON into an associative array.

(Even objects will become associative arrays and you can parse the whole object tree with the same syntax).

Then you parse the array with the square bracket syntax.

Note that both `"somkindof:blocks"` and `"some:products"` are regular arrays (ordered list of items) so you have to parse each item of them (with a simple `foreach`)

Said that you may have **many** "I want this".

```
<?php

$jfo = json_decode($vcurl, true ); // <-- decode into associative array

foreach( $jfo[ "embedded" ][ "somkindof:blocks" ] as $level_1_item )
{
    foreach( $level_1_item[ "_embedded" ][ "some:products" ] as $level_2_item )
    {
        $iWantThis = $level_2_item[ "IWANTTHIS" ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thx this tool: http://jsonselector.com

```
$channel = ['_embedded']['somkindof:blocks'][0]['_embedded']['some:products'][0]['system']['IWANTTHIS']
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `true` as second parameter to json_decode to decode it into an array and not object.

```
<?php
$json = '{
  "type": "page",
  "pageType": "section",
  "_links": {},
  "_embedded": {
    "somkindof:blocks": [
      {
        "somevalue": 25,
        "_embedded": {
          "some:products": [
            {
              "system": {
                "availability": {},
                "IWANTTHIS": "20284",
                "hhhh": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}';

$jfo = json_decode($json, true);

$channel = $jfo['_embedded']['somkindof:blocks'];
print_r($channel);
```

Answer (score 0):

All comments have suggested the Array option by providing `true` to [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.

However, if you wish to maintain `stdClass` use curly brackets.

Eg:

```
$jfo = json_decode($json);

foreach($jfo->_embedded->{'somkindof:blocks'} as $block) {
    echo $block->{'somSomething is wrongue'};
}
```